# Lost highlighting of found text in Notepad++

Tags: colors, notepad++

When I search for text (any coding language) in NPP, I used to see the "hit" string highlighted. After a brief bit of playing around in Global styles in Style Configurator, I get no highlighting any longer. The hit string is still the normal (white) background and the text foreground color is unaffected. Yes, I tried change Settings/Style Configurator/Search Results (all options there), and I tried changing anything set to have a white background in Global. BTW, "selected text" still shows up successfully with a yellow background color.

I dimly recall there's a style-configuring text file, and I once, long ago, made an edit in that. I wonder if that's now messed up.

Comment: I just restored stylers.xml from a backup and the problem remains.

Comment: Restoring config.xml and functionList.xml didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Regular Expression searches don't do the highlighting. Unclicking that option in the search dlg box solved the problem.